# Django template variable not set

Tags: django, django-templates

The title says everything. Two days ago the following code worked fine but now `journeys` is not set or empty or ...

```
def map(request, jid):
    journeys = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        journeys = Journey.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)

    #some stuff

    context = {
        'jc': len(journeys), #only for testing
        'journeys': journeys
    }

    return render(request, 'JourneyMap/map.html', context)
```

map.html extends base.html

**Inside base.html:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown05">
    <p>{{ jc }}</p> <-- only for testing
    {% for journey in journeys %}
        {% if journey.user_id == user.user_id %}
            {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}
                <a class="dropdown-item"
                   href="{% url 'JourneyMap_journey' jid=journey.id %}">{{ journey.title }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `journeys` length is 1, so the variable is actually set.

I think that your user check fails here.

`{% if journey.user_id == user.user_id %}`

What is `user.user_id` here? Is `user` another variable that lives somewhere outside of the given context? Then probably it's not set.

Otherwise, if you want to check for current user's id, perhaps you should do:

`{% if journey.user_id == request.user.id %}`

Comment: `user` is a django short cut for `request.user`. using `request.user...` or setting user by myself in the context does not change anything. I also tried to output the `user.user_id` and the `journey-user_id` and they are the same. Also the code showed in the question is surrounded by an `if user.is_authenticated`. So this means the user is set also because I can output the id.

Comment: I don't see the reason for checking `user` in template when you are filtering by the authenticated user in your views `Journey.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)`

Comment: Yes, i also assumed that it's a different `user` and not the django default `user` in `request`. @Matze, have you tried removing that check from the template? Is the dropdown empty again?

Comment: yes just tried it, because I realized its redundant because I already filter it by the id inside the view method. Unfortunately does not change anything.

Comment: Instead of outputting `<p>{{ jc }}</p>` in template, can you do `<p>{{journeys.count}}</p>`? Is it still 1?

Comment: I tried it. Still 1. But I found the error. But it does not make any sense. The for loop counter is broken. When I do this `<p>{{ forloop.counter }}</p>` It outputs a random number. Last try it was `97379011`

Comment: That seems weird.